# If $\bar{k}\supseteq R\supseteq k$, then $R$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Say $R$ is an integral domain and $k$ is a field.

Is it true that if $\bar{k}\supseteq R\supseteq k$, then $R$ is a field?

I'm not sure how to show this immediately, and it seems to be implied in the textbook, or else they are using some other facts not listed.

Comment: How is the textbook implying that? It isn't true, so...

Comment: @Chessanator It *is* true.

Comment: Whoops, yeah. Just ignore me.

Comment: (by the way, the requirement that $R$ is a domain is superfluous)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44374/intermediate-ring-between-a-field-and-an-algebraic-extension), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879987/if-f-subset-d-subset-e-then-d-must-be-a-field?rq=1) for finite extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Let $\alpha$ be any element of $R$. Consider the homomorphism $\nu_\alpha:k[x]\to R$, $\nu_\alpha(p)=p(\alpha)$. Since $\alpha$ is algebraic over $k$, $\ker\nu_\alpha$ contains a non-zero polynomial. $\ker\nu_\alpha$ must therefore be a non-zero *prime* ideal of $k[x]$. Since $k[x]$ is PID, non-zero pime ideals are maximal. So $\operatorname{im}\nu_\alpha$ is a field: in other words, there is some $\beta\in\operatorname{im}\nu_\alpha$ such that $\beta\alpha=1$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.